# Why does muggle-born Hermione call Voldemort “You-Know-Who”?

Tags: harry-potter

She also winces and jumps when Harry uses his name.

Comment: Possibly because she likes obeying rules, and it's an unspoken rule that you don't use his name?

Comment: Well, it's a scary name.  [See also](http://www.hpmor.com/chapter/3) (search for "Voldemort").

Comment: This seems to be essentially the same question as the one linked, so I [closed it as a duplicate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates). If yours is not covered by that question, you can [edit] to explain the difference(s).

Answer (score 7):

When Hermione meets Harry for the first time in Chapter Six of *Philosopher's Stone*, she tells him:

> I know all about you, of course -- I got a few extra books for background reading, and you're in *Modern Magical History* and *The Rise and Fall of the Dark Arts* and *Great
>   Wizarding Events of the Twentieth Century*.

If she knows about Harry from reading those books, then logically she'd also know all about Voldemort, his reign of terror, and the taboo surrounding his name. Hermione's a very compassionate person, and it makes sense to me that she'd join in with the taboo to avoid upsetting or offending anyone.

Comment: There's a difference between not using the name to avoid upsetting people and showing fear herself when someone says the name. Additionally, Dumbledore encourages people to say the name, and she admires Dumbledore, so that would be a reason for her to use the name, despite peoples' reactions.